# AWS OpsWorks SSH Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

In order to deploy an instance of a Rails application on AWS OpsWorks, I have to define an SSH key for the instance. I followed the steps provided in the help page: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workinginstances-ssh.html#workinginstances-ssh-third

1. I created the key pair and downloaded the `.pem` file: AWSRails.pem
2. I've changed the `chmod` of the file to 600
3. In the stack page, I added the default SSH key to the previously created one (step 1)
4. In the Instance page, I get the public DNS name: ec2-54-72-154-78.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
5. In the same page, I get the Operating system: Amazon Linux
6. In the terminal, I attempted to establish a ssh connection to the instance:

   ssh -v -i ~/Downloads/AWSRails.pem ec2-user@ec2-54-72-154-78.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com

I had the following output:

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-54-72-154-78.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com [54.72.154.78] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file AWSRails.pem type -1
debug1: identity file AWSRails.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA f0:52:63:a5:cf:d9:62:bc:f7:b9:f9:04:a7:05:93:5e
debug1: Host 'ec2-54-72-154-78.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/Hassen/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/Hassen/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: AWSRails.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Reading the debug message, the connexion was established and everything works fine, until publickey authentication method. I tried many of the same issues found on StackOverflow, but none worked.

Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: are you sure you didn't create your instance with Ubuntu? Does the instance show up in amazon dashboard as having AWSRails.pem as its key?

Comment: You're right on the second point. I had to shutdown the instance and add the pem key... Now, I can't relaunch the instance (fails during the setup phase,) and still having publickey error when deploying from github: `Permission denied (publickey)`. But I can access to the remote AWS instance with SSH.

Comment: agreed with the first comment. are you positive you used the amazon linux instance type? the ubuntu instance has a different default user.

Answer (score 0):

Two potential solutions:

1. Do you have SSH turned on for your user? Check your Permissions (from the dashboard IIRC). If it's just you on the stack then probably you already have permissions, but I know I've had to make sure to turn it when adding members to my development team. [For more details see the AWS OpsWorks page on SSH](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workinginstances-ssh.html)
2. All my "ssh into OpsWorks instances" scripts always do `ssh add-key ec2-keypair.pem` before actually trying to SSH. I believe this is the key given to you during initial stack creation??? or something? Anyway, if you have that key around, try `ssh add-key`. It may also depend on how you have your OpsWorks set up (personal keys vs one default key)...

Answer (score 0):

It’s worth checking if the username is what you expect it to be. I had *exactly* the same error, and it was because I was using Ubuntu instances rather than Amazon Linux, but this may not be the only reason for having a different username.

The Opsworks console’s SSH login page suggests `userexamplecom` as the SSH username for an AWS/IAM user with `user@example.com` as a login. But for Ubuntu it’s `ubuntu`, Amazon Linux or Red Hat it’s `ec2-user`, and Debian it’s `admin`. [More details here](https://alestic.com/2014/01/ec2-ssh-username/) (I haven’t used all of these personally).

A good tip from the linked article is to try:

```
$ ssh root@hostname
```

As some systems will respond with something like:

```
Please login as the user "ubuntu" rather than the user "root".
```